# Rx.Net Window operator that opens on first value and next value after closing

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'd like to make a Reactive Extension Window-operator, that:

1. Opens a window on the first value (not on subscribe)
2. Closes that window on a given timeout after that value
3. Opens a new window on the first value after closing

Thus never creating overlaps, but allowing gaps.

I have been unsuccessful so far. Does anyone have a good idea how to do that?

Comment: I started mocking something up with `Select`, `Scan` and `Materialize`, but it's much uglier than your solution. It's possible though.

Answer (score 0):

A GroupByUntil seems to do the trick:

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> LazyWindow<T, TClosing>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Func<IObservable<TClosing>> windowClose) => source
        .GroupByUntil(x => 0, group => windowClose())
        .Select(x => (IObservable<T>) x);
```

EDIT: Don't use `null` as the constant group key, it resulted in NRE's within the framework. Very strange.